# Python openpyxl loop through excel files in folder

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, smtplib

I have working code, but it takes forever to loop through about 35 .xlsx files, read values in column J (including comparing cell values to a dictionary) and then do some comparisons.

Basically, it's an email notification system that a) finds a person's name in a cell somewhere in column J, then examines its offset date in column A.  If the date in column A is one day in the future (tomorrow) it sends that person a reminder email.

Wondering if anyone would be willing to provide some feedback!  I have a sense that the multiple fors and if's are slowing it down, but not experienced enough to know how to improve it.

Thanks for any input!  Sometimes even a little hint usually gives me enough info to work out a solution on my own.

```
try:                                                    
for i in os.listdir(os.chdir(thisdir)):
    if i.endswith(".xlsx"):
        workbook = load_workbook(i, data_only=True)
        try:
            ws = workbook[wsvar]
            cell_range = ws['j3':'j110']
            for row in cell_range: # This is iterating through rows 1-7
                for cell in row: # This iterates through the columns(cells) in that row
                    if cell.value:
                        if cell.offset(row=0, column =-9).value.date() == (datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=1)):

                            for name, email in sublist.items():
                                #send the emails
                                if cell.value == name:
                                    email = sublist[cell.value]
                                    datconv = str(cell.offset(row=0, column=-9).value.date().strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
                                    program = cell.offset(row=0, column=-7).value
                                    #if there are hours in the "hours worked column, use those"
                                    if cell.offset(row=0, column=-5).value:
                                        hours = cell.offset(row=0, column=-5).value
                                    #else, pick up the scheudled hours
                                    else:
                                        hours = cell.offset(row=0, column=-6).value
                                    #SMTP code for email goes here, but it doesn't seem to be the culprit
```

Comment: The level of nesting (4 for loops!) you have suggests that you should refactor. This might help you identify any hotspots. You're also looping though 107 rows and not  7.

Comment: @CharlieClark Yes, I agree.  I just need that "ah-ha!" moment but I don't have enough experience with a) python and b) openpyxl.  And yes, forgot to update my comments when I started looping through a larger range.

Comment: I suggest you move this to the mailing list, it will be easy to help with the refactoring. You have lots of duplicate calls, though for the number of cells that really ought not to matter.

Comment: Thanks, Charlie.  Not sure what you mean?  Move this post to another forum?

Comment: No, the openpyxl-users mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help, it works for me in a similar situation, first i red and appended all files i had (3600) to a List, then i loop them through the list, it ran faster.

Good luck

Comment: I thought of that, but I would then need to compare two items within the same list.